# What is the increment step of \fnpnodes?

Tags: pstricks, pst-node

Case 0 uses `\fnpnodes` and case 1 uses `\curvepnodes` to create nodes based on the given function(s).

```
\def\method#1{%
    \ifcase#1
        \fnpnodes[plotpoints=8]{1}{8}{\f[x]}{P}
        \psxTick(/dx \pst@number\pst@dimb\space def dx 4 mul 1 add){x_j}
    \or 
        \curvepnodes[plotpoints=8]{1}{8}{t|\f[t]}{P}    
        \psxTick(dt 4 mul 1 add){x_j}
    \fi}
```

I have known that `dt` is the increment step of `\curvepnodes`. Now I am looking for the increment step of `\fnpnodes`. I tried using `/dx \pst@number\pst@dimb\space def dx` but it does not seem to work.

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-plot,pst-node}
\psset
{
    algebraic,
    ticks=none,
    labels=none,
    plotpoints=100,
}

\def\f[#1]{sin(3*#1)/2+#1/3+1}

\makeatletter
\def\method#1{%
    \ifcase#1
        \fnpnodes[plotpoints=8]{1}{8}{\f[x]}{P}
        \psxTick(/dx \pst@number\pst@dimb\space def dx 4 mul 1 add){x_j}
    \or 
        \curvepnodes[plotpoints=8]{1}{8}{t|\f[t]}{P}    
        \psxTick(dt 4 mul 1 add){x_j}
    \fi}
\makeatother

\begin{document}    

\begin{psgraph}(0,0)(-.5,-.5)(9.5,5){12cm}{!}
    \method{1} % \method{0} does not work!
    \multido{\iL=0+1,\iR=1+1}{\Pnodecount}{\pspolygon[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=cyan!15](P\iL|0,0)(P\iL)(P\iR)(P\iR|0,0)}
    \psplot[linecolor=cyan!75!blue]{0}{9}{\f[x]}
    %\psxTick(N-P4.x){x_j} recommended
\end{psgraph}

\end{document}
```

[image]

What is the increment step of `\fnpnodes`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\fnpnodes` doesn't define an increment step on Postscript level, but the calculations are done on TeX-level. So you must do the calculations yourself with `(x1 - x0)/(plotpoints - 1)` if you need the step:

```
\fnpnodes[plotpoints=8]{1}{8}{\f[x]}{P}
\psxTick(8 1 sub 7 div 4 mul 1 add){x_j}
```